# Triggering a function on creation of an pydantic object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

is there a clean way of triggering a function call whenever I create/ instantiate a pydantic object?

Currently I am "misusing" the [`root_validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) for this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class PydanticClass(BaseModel):
  name: str

  @root_validator()
  def on_create(cls, values):
    print("Put your logic here!")
    return values
```

So on `PydanticClass(name="Test")` executes my logic and simply returns the same object values.

This works but I have two issues, which is why I would be interested in  a cleaner solution:

1. I basically don't do a validation (return the same values).
2. I think this function will also be executed once the object is changed, which I don't want.

So I am happy to learn about any better approaches/ solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your intentions are not fully clear. But I can suggest overriding the `__init__` model method. In this case, your code will be executed once at object instantiation:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class PydanticClass(BaseModel):
  name: str

  def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
      super().__init__(**data)
      print("Put your logic here!")
```

Comment: Ah, so obvious. Thanks, for the reply. Apparently this is a valid option also for the creator of pydantic: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/691#issuecomment-515409301

Answer (score 5):

As of Pydantic v2, you can now override the `model_post_init` method.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class PydanticClass(BaseModel):
  name: str

  def model_post_init(self, ctx):
      print("Put your logic here!")
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Much better than overriding the __init__ method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use python [dataclass](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) `__post_init__`:

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PydanticClass:
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        print("Post init")

pc = PydanticClass(name="Test")
print(pc)
```

[**post_init**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) is called once after `__init__` so it wouldn't be called after changes to the class instance are made.

Comment: Good to know about this but unfortunately I have used the `BaseModel` for everything so far and it seems they are still minor differences:
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/

Comment: @rayon Is there some particular difference you could highlight?

Comment: The differences are elaborated in this GitHub thread:
https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/710

Answer (score 0):

If you want this function to compute a value in your pydantic object, since `pydantic` V2 you can use the `@computed_field` decorator. You can even use it to call another function...

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    
    @computed_field
    def presented_name(self) -> str:
                  # you can even call here another function...
        return self.name + '\n'
```